# Exclude certain dependencies from class path in a maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with some dependencies. Some of them have transitive dependencies which depend on, say, some jar **A**. I want to exclude this jar. Okay, I can add exclusions to every dependency which itself depends on **A**. But its a bit tedious. Is there any way to put this exclusion in one place in a maven project configuration?

Comment: Exclude where? Exclude on the classpath when compiling, exclude from including in the final build or something else?

Comment: exclude from including in the final build.

Comment: include it with the "provided" scope

Comment: read the last line here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html  Why exclusions are made on a per-dependency basis, rather than at the POM level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, it looks like there is no way to do this.

According to documentation

**Why exclusions are made on a per-dependency basis, rather than at the POM level**

> This is mainly done to be sure the dependency graph is predictable,
>   and to keep inheritance effects from excluding a dependency that
>   should not be excluded. If you get to the method of last resort and
>   have to put in an exclusion, you should be absolutely certain which of
>   your dependencies is bringing in that unwanted transitive dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Use a parent pom where you have `<dependencyManagement/>`. Then extend this parent in your POM files.

Alternatively, if it's one project that contains all these dependencies and they contain a transitive dependency with multiple versions on the dependency tree, define that dependency explicitly in your POM file and this will override the transitive versions.

See my explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project/19703632#19703632) for a similar question.