# Making Asynchronous calls from a Spring controller gives error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, firebase

I am trying to fetch data from internet from within a spring controller but it gives a error.

```
Aug 08, 2016 11:00:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TheTest/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
Aug 08, 2016 11:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/TheTest] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    at com.indiacom.platform.util.UtilClass.getDataFromFirebaseAndMakeProject(UtilClass.java:50)
    at com.indiacom.platform.controller.MainController.AppRequest(MainController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my controller code:-

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/AppRequest" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView AppRequest(@RequestBody JobId jobId) {
      int id = jobId.getJobId();
      getDataFromInternet(id); // This method is async

      return new ModelAndView("MyJspFile");
    }
```

### Edit

This is the code that is causing this exception which is inside the `getDataFromInternet()` method:-

```
   try {
            FirebaseOptions options;
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
              .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("Argus-61523ee837f8.json"))
              .setDatabaseUrl("https://argus-1442r.firebaseio.com/")
              .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above firebase code is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).

These are the jar files that I am using apart from the Spring jars:-

[image]

I am new to Spring and unable the resolve this problem.

Comment: Check the URL you may be using in getDataFromInternet since you see "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TheTest/%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D]".

Comment: I am fetching data from firebase in getDataFromInternet()  so there's no question of a wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dependency in your project, namely:
`com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory`

It looks like adding this to your `pom.xml` will solve it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will soon give it a try.

Comment: No that's not the problem. I have included this jar yet it is not working.

Comment: Is the exception still the same than in your original question?

Comment: Exception is exactly the same.

Comment: Please read the edited question to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: well as suggested by @yglodt , clearly the json library is not in your classpath , or maybe you are using 2-3 json libraries / versions so you might have a conflict. In order to double check , please look into your .war or .jar for that google-api-client.jar in your exported application lib directory. If its there , then you have a conflict so please post your full maven configuration , if its not there then please do what yglodt suggests

Comment: @AntJavaDev : I have put all the jars in the class path. I have show all the jars i have used please check the edited question and tell me if I am using any conflicting jars as this could be highly likely.

Comment: Now it is giving me a new error after I added a new jar.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()Lcom/google/api/client/json/gson/GsonFactory;

Comment: I am just not able to understand what is the right jar combination that i should be using in my project.

Comment: then probably you have a conflict in your classpath or in your application server shared libs , except if you are using Spring Boot

Comment: oooo , i just checked your update , why you have 3 times the json-client lib ? 1.16.0 RC , 1.5.0 Beta and jackson (i am not sure if the google-http-client-jackson.jar is causing a conflict)? please recheck which dependency causes the conflict

Comment: Thanks I will check and tell.

Comment: I tried various combinatons of those 3 jars but the absence of any one of them gave some or the other classnotfoundexception.

Comment: And when I put all the three of them together it gives :  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()Lcom/google/api/‌​client/json/gson/GsonFactory;

Comment: So now I want to know which jar I should use to get rid of this exception.

Comment: if you are using the maven WTP plugin for Eclipse then in the dependencies tab , it should display which dependencies causing the conflict , or else try from a console `mvn dependency:analyze` and `mvn dependency:tree` and look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project) as well