# How to see which dependency is causing specific jar to down load into repository for maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

We have multi module environment where in  we have lot of poms that uses numerous dependencies.

1) How to see which dependency in our pom causing a specific jar to download  into repository.

Eg : I have commons-lang3 in all my poms .But some included dependency in pom's  is downloading older jars  into my repo which I need to avoid.I did
`mvn dependency:tree` but this didn't helped me.
Since my application is a mammoth its very difficult to go and see all the dependencies  that are included.

> Is there any way we can check which included dependency is causing older
>   versions of jar to download

Any one who can shed some light would be appreciated.

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: If you are using Netbeans, you can hover on the dependency(jar) in the Dependencies folder in the project. It'll show you the details like groupId, artifactId for those jars and if they are coming from some other module, it'll also show that to you in "via:..."

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit crazy, you're right but I still use most often:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

It's even crazier to read than the normal you mentioned. I do, however, agree with JF Meier here, dumping it into a text file is the way to go.

You can also search for certain things:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=project-c
```

Sometimes to get a cleaner picture though I use

```
mvn clean dependency:tree -DskipTest
```

Got these when solving another problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661765/6560068).

Comment: Thanks will look into this mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=project-c I will specify artifact and group id over here

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to know where a dependency comes from, use `dependency:tree`. I do not understand why it did not help you. Dump the result to a Text file and search for the artifacts you are interested in. Then you will immediately see where they come from.
2. If you want to set the version of a given dependency, use `<dependencyManagement>` to set the version to the one you like.

There are, of course, dependencies in your local repository which are not dependencies of your project, but are dependencies of Maven plugins.

Comment: hi Meier thanks for the response I did writing to a text file .Maybe the pom location from where I am running dependency:tree   could be wrong which is causing a vague result which is untrue but  will consider your inputs.And I am pretty sure that there are no jars in my local repository since I used to clean m2 every time before building.