# Maven: Edit parent's POM dependency (exclude or update its version)

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, dependencies

Ok, i 'll put a lot of effort to explain the complication. I am working on a project, let's say "A". This project has two other projects as dependencies, let's say "B" and "C". So, Project-A's POM is something like this:

```
<Project A>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>Project B</dependency>
        <dependency>Project C</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</Project A>
```

Both Project-B and Project-C use a module, let's say "module-X". The Project-B POM has this module-X on version 2 as a dependency, so Project-B POM is something like this:

```
<Project B>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>ModuleX_version_2</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</Project B>
```

But, Project-C inherits this module-X dependency on version 1 from another parent project, so Project-C POM is something like:

```
<Project C>
    <parent>
        < Project-C-Parent >
    </parent>
</Project C>
```

and finally Project-C-Parent is something like this:

```
<Project C-Parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>ModuleX_version_1</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</Project C-Parent>
```

The conflict that occurs is the following: in Project-A, in a Project-B-function which uses the module-X, instead this function to use the version_2 it uses the version_1 that has been imported from Project-C (and of course an error pops-up).

The problem would be solved if:
a) everything uses module-X on version_2.
b) project-B uses version_2 and project-C uses version_1, without these two being confused.

I don't have access to change any other POM except from mine (project-A). I tried to use exclusions(for module-X) on project-C dependency but it didn't work because the module-X is not present in project-C's POM but in its parent.

So, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mention the right version of X in the A pom and that version will be used. In other words, explicitly add the X dependency to the A pom. This tells maven which version of X that you want.

This will make it so that A depends on the specified version of X. For example, if A creates a war, then that war will include the specified version of the X jar.

Note that if the two different versions of X are not compatible with each other, then code that you call in C will likely have problems (and there is nothing maven can do about that). See [this question for related information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project).

Comment: Unfortunately i have already tried it and it didn't worked out, the module_X is being included again from project-C in version_1 and the same conflict occurs...Again, on my external libraries tree i have:
-module_x_v2
-projectC (which again includes module_x_v1)
.
Thanks for the related post though :)