# How to remove jar file from classpath during runtime?

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Apache Commons library (commons-io.jar) added to my project classpath and I want to remove this library classes from my classpath during runtime and then I want to add after some work.

Is there any way to remove all classes from classpath during runtime and add these classes after some operation?

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    //Some apache commons operations

    //Remove apache commons classes from classpath

    doSomeWork();

    //Add apache commons classes to classpath

}
```

Comment: very much doubt it, but, more importantly, why would you want that?

Comment: @Stultuske There is a conflict between libraries and I must use both of these libraries.

Comment: I suggest Maven to handle that

Comment: Yeah, this is a configuration issue, not something you solve through code.

Comment: @Java that's really not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is known as **classpath hell**.

There is no such functionality in Java. The reason behind this is the design of classloaders, which can only load classes and not unload them. In all likelyhood, this is not going to happen even in the future.

You could use a special classloader to load different classes from different jars, but even this way you quickly stumble into other limitations. For example, *a classloader should only load the class if the parent has not yet loaded it*. This means that other parts of your code cannot use apache-commons.jar. You could separate your program into two parts and have each run in its own classloader/classpath, but then you'll realize you *can't share objects between them* anymore. And so on.

In the end, you can either (a) try to find a combination of jars that works with both, (b) fix one part of the program so that it works with the other jar, or (c) break the program into two parts and have each run in separate JVMs.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the maven-enforcer-plugin in your pom to force specific versions of the transitive dependencies.
[Conflicting library version in a java maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659425/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project)

Comment: No he couldn't. You are providing a build-time solution to a runtime problem.