# How to identify potential java dependiny namespace conflicts in maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, namespaces, applicationcontext

I have several huge legacy applications that I am now working on. After months of testing, we finally reached deployment only to have a "failed to load webapplicationcontext" which foiled the whole endeavor. That specific failure was due to a name space conflict between two transitive dependencies. i.e., both jars had a class to load as: org.something.somethingelse.ClassName.

There are ~100 jars pulled in via maven for this single project. Several explicit, most transitive. Ideally, I would like to know every single jar I'm putting on my classpath. Practically, though, I don't have enough experience or time to look through every one of them for potential issues.

Is there a tool, technique, or eclipse/intelliJ feature that I can use to scan a set of jars for similar namespaces?

Comment: this have nothing to do with spring, it is just dependency hell - maybe you need something like this: http://pettermahlen.com/2010/08/05/finding-duplicate-class-definitions-using-maven/  - this blogpost is quite old, and hopefully this fork has been merged into the main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a couple of different solutions here. I ended up using jhades (http://jhades.github.io/) to identify conflicts within the war, and then tattletale (a utility provided by JBOSS support) to identify conflicts between the war and the container.

I added 'exclude *' tags to all the explicit dependencies to prevent any transitive dependencies from loading. I added explicit dependencies for anything that still wasn't present. After ensuring that all compiled dependencies played nicely, I set any libraries identified by tattletale to provided and added the necessary module to standalone.xml. These things like hibernate, apache libs, servlet APIs etc.

The other thing I discovered which made this so difficult to identify in the first place is that JBOSS's classloader indexes libraries according to how the hosting file system orders them. On Windows, which is where we do 90% of our development, they are always loaded alphabetically. On linux, where we do our production deployments, the order is pseudo random. Our production servers are built from the same images, so a RHEL 3.4 server will load in the same order as another 3.4, but a 3.5 will load entirely differently. Thus, we did not see a failure until the stars aligned and we deployed to a 3.6 server. In production.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html). In a maven project, it's very usefull when you need to detect different jar depenndencies of same artifact with different version.

You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365201/how-do-i-get-maven-to-fail-when-conflicting-versions-of-the-same-artifact-are-re) too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the enforcer plugin, and the article you linked, only check artifact Id and version, not the actual package declarations within the jars. The incident that triggered this post was hibernate-core, and org.springsource.hibernate. Two different jars, two different artifact ids, but the same package and classnames. It's relatively easy to identify those jars (now that i've stumbled over them once), but i'm concerned about other jars that may not be so easily identified. We have hundreds of jars on the classpath, and that is for only a single application.